# Double element definition when creating an AX custom web service

Tags: c#, web-services, axapta, ax

We have created a custom web service from AX and we are invoking it from several different application.

The problem we are facing is that we have some elements that are defined twice in the service reference.

For instance I get this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
public string Company {
    get {
        return this.companyField;
    }
    set {
        this.companyField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Company");
    }
}
```

defined twice. Similarly I have this error:

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'company.customer.AxIntegrationWorkflows.AxWebServices.CallContext.RaisePropertyChanged(string)' and 'company.customer.AxIntegrationWorkflows.AxWebServices.CallContext.RaisePropertyChanged(string)'

By removing the second definition from the service reference we managed it to get working.
But why is it happening in the first place?

Comment: Did you find the cause of this problem?

Comment: Yes. The AX custom web service was being deployed with the same endpoint as the standard ones. Changing it to a custom endpoint removed that problem